# How to loop through multiple paths using pathlib

Tags: python, loops, pathlib

Trying to list, for example, all the jpgs on two drives.
Single drive search looks like:

```
from pathlib import Path

for path in Path("/Volumes/MasterOne").rglob('*'):
    for file_name in path.glob('*.jpg'):   
        print(file_name)
```

But am not finding how to add a second volume to the for loop and iterate for files on both drives.

```
paths = ("/Volumes/MasterOne", "/Volumes/MasterTwo")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might add outer `for` to get desired behavior as follows

```
from pathlib import Path

for p in ("/Volumes/MasterOne", "/Volumes/MasterTwo"):
    for path in Path(p).rglob('*'):
        for file_name in path.glob('*.jpg'):   
            print(file_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try different type of loops! As `if else` and `for` loops pretty much helps around!

```
for p in ("/Volumes/MasterOne", "/Volumes/MasterTwo"):
    for path in Path(p).rglob('*'):
        for file_name in path.glob('*.jpg'):   
            print(file_name)
```